# python function in which a parameter is external if mentioned or internal if it is not mentioned

Tags: python

I would like to define a Python function in which a parameter is external if it is declared when the function is called and it is internal if it is not mentioned into the function calling.
An easy example will clarify my issue:

```
def func(a, b):
    c = 4
    try:
        b
    except:
        b= c
    return a + b
```

Now I want something in which I can write

```
func(2, 1)
```

and provide me the result (2 + 1 = 3), and I can even write

```
func(2)
```

and the function will generate a solution that is c + a = 6.

How can I do that?

Comment: Side note: **never** use a bare `except:`.  Specify the exception you want to catch as: `except ValueError`, or `except NameError` etc.  Otherwise you will block *everything*, including stuff like interrupt signals or memory errors which is something you should *never* catch, since you really cannot actually handle them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  are describing a default argument. Python does that for you ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)):

```
def func(a, b=4):
    return a + b
```

Alternatively, if more logic is involved, you might want to consider:

```
def func(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        try:
            b = fancy_function()
        except FancyException:
            b = 4
    return a + b
```

The same holds for mutable default values:

```
def func(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = []
    b.append(a)
    return b
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply write

```
def func(a, b=4):
    return a + b

>>> func(2)
6
>>> func(2, 1)
3
```

If the default value of `b` is not known beforehand, you can do the following:

```
def func(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = some_function_that_generates_b()
    return a + b
```

Comment: The problem is that in my case b can be generated into the function from opening a file and processing the data that are inside. So I would prefer something that says: "if b is declared into the function calling than use it, otherwise do this task and generate b from inside"